# UITableViewController odd behavior

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uitableview

Sorry if this question look stupid but after hours of digging and searching with no success, I need to ask it here for you help.
I have a `UITableViewController` with 15 custom cell. Each cell has a `UITextField` inside.

here is the part of code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    Static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ADDFIELDCELL";
    AddListContentCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[AddListContentCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }


    [cell.myTextField setTag:[self.tagsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] integerValue]];

    return cell;
}
```

The problem is when I type something in first cell (indexPath:0) after scroll down same text appear on 13th cell also. same mapping happens with 2nd and 14th cell.

I am really out of temper and do not what should I do. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cell is being **reused** (hence the reuse identifier).

The textfield text for each cell needs to be linked to the datasource somehow (seems to be your tags array).

When you change the text on that cell, you have to modify the datasource text.

This way when the cell at index 2 rolls around, it will fill the textfield with whatever your tag item at index 2 of your datasource array has.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I have set the `delegate` of all `textField`s to self. which method should I use to store the inserted text to dataArray? didFinishEditing or what?????

Comment: You could set it to self (in the cell subclass). Then call down from the cell using your own protocol (because you'll need the index of the cell where the edit occurred).  You can send the message from textFieldDidEndEditing

Comment: BTW, variables should start with lowercase